# Why is the output undefined here?

Tags: javascript, frontend

```
var object = { _text: 'Hello World', getInvite: function() {return this._text}}; 
var func= object.getInvite; 
console.log(func());
```

Is it because here the function is being invoked not within the context of the object? Which makes 'this' undefined?

Comment: Try to put `()` at the end, id est, use func=object.getInvite();

Comment: console.log(func) will give expected out as func variable is defined but func function

Comment: You need to bind `func` back to the original object before calling it, e.g. `func.bind(object)()`

Comment: This is not a duplicate my question is different @inostia

Comment: @amy can you explain the reason?

Comment: I believe the reason here is related to the behavior of 'this' in Javascript, I thought someone would mention that. Anyone?

Comment: Please stop duplicating this post, I asked for an explanation. Hope you people get it.

Comment: The first three answers in the linked question answers your question, if you care to read them.  If your question is a duplicate, it's a duplicate.  Whether you want an explanation isn't relevant.

Answer (score -1):

It's because when you assign `object.getInvite` to `func` it loses reference to the rest of the "object" object.

`object.getInvite()` works because object has a property called `_text` while `func` is just a stand alone function which has no references to `_text` anymore.